# An Italian-styled crossword puzzle

Tags: crosswords

This new puzzle consists of a crossword. For those who don't know this is done using the Italian style (as opposed to US/UK), so two-letter words are allowed and defined. This crossword puzzle has a 180 rotational symmetry.

The definitions are given in a block style because even in this format the question becomes really long. Feel free to use the image here provided to show the solution in your answer, however, any other drawing method is fine.

[image]

**Across:**
**1.** Low dams built across a river. (5) — **4.** In a faint or indistinct way. (5) — **9.** Technology previously used in electronic devices, especially camera or TV. (3) — **11.** It denotes subatomic particles. (2) — **12.** Departure from an accepted standard. (9) — **15.** It expresses agreement in southern Europe. (2) — **16.** The place where a famous festival takes place since 1977. (4) — **17.** In an extremely unpleasant way. (8) — **21.** Between machine and user. (2) — **22.** Small surgical instrument used to remove via scraping. (7) — **24.** Celestial body. (3) — **26.** Caesium. (2) — **28.** Usually, it's the director's version. (5) — **29.** Expressing gratitude informally. (2) — **30.** One of the moons of Jupiter. (2) — **31.** Anger. (3) — **33.** Australasian flowering shrub or small tree. (2) — **34.** Small sea within Indonesia between islands of Sumba, Flores, and Timor. (4) — **36.** Consciousness characterized by pure passive receptiveness without understanding. (7) — **38.** Gnawing animals with constantly growing incisors. (7) — **39.** Star with wavy points or rays. (7) — **41.** Expressing past ownership or possession in Old English. (4) — **43.** Prefix that expresses transitive action. (2) — **44.** Format for data compression. (3) — **45.** They're not odd in Kuru. (2) — **46.** A long playing record. (2) — **47.** Plots of land marked off for building purposes. (5) — **49.** A letter in the Greek alphabet. (2) — **50.** American late-night sketch comedy show. (3) — **52.** Most strange and frightening. (7) — **55.** United States' Georgia. (2) — **57.** Young dancers were doing it in the 60s. (8) — **59.** Bones in anatomy. (4) — **61.** It negates auxiliary verbs in English. (2) — **62.** The doctrine that spirits exist and are distinct from matter. (9) — **64.** Attorneys that have no liability arising from the malpractice of their associates. (2) — **65.** Name used for someone whose identity is unknown. (3) — **66.** Resulting from burning. (5) — **67.** They can store food... or a missile. (5)

**Down:**
**1.** They usually have checkered shirts and a beard. (10) — **2.** When attached, it forms verbs. (2) — **3.** A large constellation with the Galaxy situated in its center. (11) — **4.** A state of disuse. (9) — **5.** A plant with purple or yellow flowers, native to both Eurasia and North America. (4) — **6.** In the army, it's used to address an officer cadet. (2) — **7.** It's very likely to get lost in one. (9) — **8.** It forms names of compounds containing a triple bond. (3) — **9.** The belief that people are only motivated by self-interest. (8) — **10.** Active predatory schooling fish of warm seas. (4) — **13.** A vineyard of recognized superior quality. (3) — **14.** A neck ornament consisting of a band of twisted metal. (4) — **18.** He... wants it at the declaration of the First Crusade by Pope Urban II. (4) — **19.** In Hebrew, it indicates a symbol. (2) — **20.** Natural exclamation, first recorded in Old English. (2) — **23.** Having or consisting of one. (3) — **25.** The promotions of a person or organization. (11) — **27.** Title of respect used before the name of a man or a god in India. (3) — **32.** It denotes things that are fundamental or needed. (10) — **35.** Done on one's free will. (9) — **36.** Consisting of two short or unstressed syllables followed by one long or stressed syllable. (9) — **37.** Finely grooved or furrowed. (8) — **40.** A member of a family of metal wind instruments. (3) — **42.** Famous environmental activist who inspired a movie with her name. (4) — **43.** Grotesque Egyptian god who dispelled evil spirits. (3) — **48.** Spanish dramatist and poet from the Spanish Golden Century. (4) — **51.** Band of the electromagnetic spectrum between 148.5 and 283.5 kHz. (2) — **53.** Used in France when listing various items. (2) — **54.** Smelling extremely unpleasant. (4) — **56.** Small southern European viper. (3) — **58.** Former monetary unit of Peru. (4) — **60.** Small mouthful of liquid. (3) — **63.** In the middle of the circ. (2) — **64.** A river in Northern Italy. (2)

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> WEIRS DIMLY CRT
> OD  ABERRANCY U
> O T G SI BERN N
> D ODIOUSLY UI A
> CURETTE ORB CS 
> UNCUT TY IO IRE
> TO SAVU ANOESIS
> T S RODENTS M S
> ESTOILE AHTE BE
> RAR UU LP ERVEN
>  XI SNL EERIEST
> O GA TWISTING I
> L OSSA NT S A A
> I SPIRITISM  PL
> DOE PYRIC SILOS
> ```

I think I read TORC, which I did not have yet, somewhere last night in reference to a definition; which kind of cascaded to fill the rest of my blanks. So thanks(ish :p) to @Rand al'Thor in the chat;

Comment: Rosie noticed a mistake, I fixed 66a.

Answer (score 4):

**Final solution:**

> [image: crossword]

Thanks to @Deusovi for help with [9 across](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33001236#33001236) and [36 across](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33000819#33000819).

Comment: If your 60d is correct, doesn't that show an error in the construction of the crossword -- your 66a seems to need a correction which unfortunately contradicts 60d.

Comment: Rosie noticed a mistake, I fixed 66a.