# A cubic colored pyramid

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle, no-computers

While preparing the next puzzle for publishing, I decided to encrypt the file to protect it, but something went wrong or maybe I entered the wrong command because the puzzle was encrypted, yes, but not the way I was expecting it to be! Instead of becoming an unaccessible file, it became another puzzle entirely!

However this gave me an idea, would you be able to solve it and understand what puzzle it used to be? What do the cubes mean?

Here's the "encrypted" puzzle, **click to zoom**.

[image]

### Notes:

1. The parts relevant to the puzzle are the colors and the letters only.
2. The lines in the cube faces are there to identify the colors (for colorblind users). I'll provide a table with the colors and color names below, along with the patterns.
3. The numbers on each cube are there for you to make it easier to reference a puzzle, so you can say "the cube #33" instead of "the cube in the center but slightly to the right".
4. The "hidden" faces of the cubes are not part of the puzzle.

### Colors used:

[image]

Comment: Finally someone that cares about the color blind. +1 for that...and for the fact that this is a nice puzzle.

Comment: Are we supposed to be able to read letters on the black faces?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No, the black faces are empty.

Comment: Empty meaning they genuinely aren't meant to have letters on them, or empty meaning we can't see the letters that would be visible there if they weren't black?

Comment: (Of course you might prefer not to say.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Empty meaning empty. :P

Comment: What'd you use to make that diagram? It looks awesome :)

Comment: This looks cool, and i really love that you put some work into just making this puzzle more accessible (namely the lines for the color blind and the numbers for easy reference). Now let's just hope this is fun to solve ;)

Comment: @Timme Thank you! I don't think it's hard to solve, looks may deceive. As always, observing patterns or similar details will help you figure out what might be happening! :)

Comment: All the information you need is in the question, nothing is hidden (no steganography, no hidden letters with similar color values, etc).

Comment: I'm too lazy to do it myself, but I would start by "looking" at the pyramid from all 3 different directions (x,y,z if you will..)... note that there is a consistent alignment on the letters in each face/direction, I think it's not a simple coincidence.

Comment: A bounty for a question I finally know the answer of but can't answer! :D

Comment: @Alenanno a hint perhaps?

Comment: @Areeb Well, I kinda have already (see comments above), but I'm afraid I can't say any more than that. Especially not now that it has a bounty.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am able to solve it!  The puzzle when decrypted is a:

> Crossword Puzzle - Similar to [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44518/an-italian-styled-crossword-puzzle)

Each cube is:

> Encoded in order top face, left face, right face.  They are then ordered in row major order then left to right.  The same order as the numbers in the image.

The key is:

> Each letter refers to the index of the letter in the colour of the cube.  So for Red A=r,B=e,C=d.  Blacks indicate empty spaces.

This was discovered:

> by noticing that all of the letters were small except for very few.  The large letters were all assigned to the colours with longer names.  Decoding the first few cubes from the top let me know I was on the right path.

After decrypting:

> The puzzle needed to be arranged into a grid.

The original puzzle:.

> `colored_stupas_dpi`
> `atlas_er_earlobe_n`
> `m_arvicole_fuji_mt`
> `eon_poe_ate_musca_`
> `life_nitrogen_hinc`
> `oland_victor_conto`
> `tris_deceased_peru`
> `_irate_hnl_cue_aap`
> `pg_tail_isotopes_l`
> `e_verglas_ne_istle`
> `red_entity_decreet`

(edit by OP) Here's the graphical solution:

> [image]

Comment: Great! How did you come up with that? What was the decisive thought, hint or link?

Comment: @friedemann_bach I have updated my answer to include that.

Comment: xD Ahah good job! Do you mind if I add the "solved puzzle" in graphical form?

Comment: That would be excellent @Alenanno.

Comment: @LeppyR64 By the way, you made a couple of mistakes when converting (nothing critical).

Comment: @Alenanno I will go over it again.  My transcription did match elias answer though.

Comment: @LeppyR64 I fixed it for you. See the edit. :D

Comment: @Alenanno Yellow D is not L? Cube 36

Comment: @LeppyR64 Let me check real quick.

Comment: @LeppyR64 You're right. There are a couple of mistakes on my part. I'll fix the puzzle in the main question. I guess I got confused from all the stuff I had to do.

Comment: @Alenanno It's a wonderful puzzle.  Mistakes happen :)  Let me know when you do the update and I'll correct my answer, or you can propose the edits yourself if you see fit.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Fixed. Cubes 36 and 57 (both right face). I don't think there are other mistakes (I checked).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49985/discussion-between-leppyr64-and-alenanno).